# Create link to server controller's action in BlazorWeb assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, blazor

I'm writing an app using WebAssembly Blazor hosted by ASP.NET Core. Some of pages are implemented in Blazor, but some old pages are still ASP.NET Core Razor views. I need to create a link in Blazor component pointing to action of controller on server.

I can write:

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("SomeContoller/SomeAction/123", true)
```

But I don't want to hardcode url to action, because changing server routing or contoller/action names will break such links. Is there any way to create proper links via some helper, similar to ASP.Net Core UriHelper? Like:

```
UriHelper.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", new {id = 123});
```

Answer (score 3):

In Blazor server apps you can use [`LinkGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator). The usage is not much different that of `UriHelper`:

```blazor
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
@inject LinkGenerator LinkGenerator

<a href="@LinkGenerator.GetPathByAction("SignIn", "Authentication")">Sign in</a>
```

ReSharper understands this one too, so you will get auto-completion for controller and action names.

In WebAssembly apps `LinkGenerator` is not available, so your best bet is to dump all routes from the server and implement your own link generator which uses that data on the client (its complexity depends on complexity of your routes, the one from ASP.NET Core is quite complex).

```charp
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

namespace BlazorTest.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/routes")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RouteInformationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly EndpointDataSource _endpointDataSource;

        public RouteInformationController(EndpointDataSource endpointDataSource)
        {
            _endpointDataSource = endpointDataSource;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> Get()
        {
            foreach (var endpoint in _endpointDataSource.Endpoints.OfType<RouteEndpoint>())
            {
                var actionDescriptor = endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();
                if (actionDescriptor == null)
                    continue;

                yield return new
                {
                    actionDescriptor.ControllerName,
                    actionDescriptor.ActionName,
                    Parameters = actionDescriptor.Parameters.Select(p => p.Name),
                    RoutePattern = endpoint.RoutePattern.RawText,
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions/) is a bit outdated. Should we still add it to WASM 3.x or 5.x project? Or there is a way to inject LinkGenerator without using this NuGet package?

Comment: @KasbolatKumakhov You shouldn't, it will not work anyway unless you pull onto client all your controllers and most of ASP.NET Core. I just didn't notice that the question was specifically about WASM. I have updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static class with constant properties in it for all the URLs that you use in the app. After that use the same static class property in both the page route and your navigation route. Below is a very basic version of this:

```
public static class RouteUrls
{
    public static string Home = "/Home";
    public static string ProductList = "/Product";
    public static string ProductDetail = "/Product/Detail";
    public static string SomePage = "/SomeContoller/SomeAction";
}

// to access it use like this:
NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"{RouteUrls.SomePage}/123", true)
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks promising, because now routes are in one place. But still, it doesn't rely on ASP.NET endpoint routing, therefore changing a controller name without overriding standard route `{controller}/{action}/{id?}` will break links.